# advantage of creating node server in background

Tags: node.js, express

Until today in all my node\express projects, I have created  the HTTP server in some file

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = maxSockets;
    server.listen(port, function() {
        logger.info('App starting on : ' + port );
    });
```

and called that file directly to start the app. Recently i am noticing some boilerplates, using the approach  of calling a starter file and based on arguments, spawn a  child process, be it building the app or starting the app

```
in package json
"start": "babel-node tools/run.js"


in run .js
// Launch `node build/server.js` on a background thread
function spawnServer() {
  return cp.spawn(
    'node',
    [
      // Pre-load application dependencies to improve "hot reload" restart time
      ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).reduce(
        (requires, val) => requires.concat(['--require', val]),
        [],
      ),
      // If the parent Node.js process is running in debug (inspect) mode,
      // launch a debugger for Express.js app on the next port
      ...process.execArgv.map(arg => {
        if (arg.startsWith('--inspect')) {
          const match = arg.match(/^--inspect=(\S+:|)(\d+)$/);
          if (match) debugPort = Number(match[2]) + 1;
          return `--inspect=${match ? match[1] : '0.0.0.0:'}${debugPort}`;
        }
        return arg;
      }),
      '--no-lazy',
      // Enable "hot reload", it only works when debugger is off
      ...(isDebug
        ? ['./server.js']
        : [
            '--eval',
            'process.stdin.on("data", data => { if (data.toString() === "load") require("./server.js"); });',
          ]),
    ],
    { cwd: './build', stdio: ['pipe', 'inherit', 'inherit'], timeout: 3000 },
  );
}
```

eg : https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter/

how is this advantageous?

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking about.  Maybe if you could show a specific way of launching a server and ask about that?  The link you posted is to a big project and it is not obvious what that has to do with this question.  I have a node.js server running on a raspberry Pi and I launch it with `forever` because then if it crashes, `forever` will automatically restart it and will capture and coordinate logs for me.

Comment: i have added code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this is not a widespread practice.  It appears based on the comments that they're doing it in order to be able to do configuration on command line options based on the environment and so on.  To be honest, this seems a bit counterproductive to me.

What I've seen far more often is to start node from the command line with just `npm start`.  `package.json` has several options for defining what that will do, but most often I would just have it call something simple like `node server.js` or similar.  If you have multiple options for starting that you want to offer (for example, turning on the debug flags and such), then just add more scripts and call `npm run <scriptname>` to make it happen.

Any other special sauce would be baked into the process manager of choice (systemd is my preference but others like pm2 exist and work well), and between that and the environment variables you can do all or most of what's in the above script without all the indirection.   I feel like the example you posted would really up the 'wtf-factor' if I were starting to maintain the app and didn't know that at it was doing things like that for me under the hood.